# Order Collection by Relevance

Tags: collection, query

I have a custom collection for my extension and am trying to implement search functionality. This would be pretty easy if I was using regular MySQL expressions but can't seem to get it working with Magento's available collection methods.

Here is the code I have:

```
/** @var Pvtl_Consult_Model_Resource_Consultations_Collection $customers_collection */
$customers_collection = Mage::getModel('pvtl_consult/consultations')->getCollection();

$customers_collection
    ->join('pvtl_consult/consultants', 'consult_consultant = consultant_id')
    ->addFieldToFilter('consult_lastname', array(
        array('like' => $search),
        array('like' => '%' . $search),
        array('like' => $search . '%'),
        array('like' => '%' . $search . '%')
    )
)
    ->addFieldToFilter('consultant_store', $store_id);

$customers_collection->getSelect()->order(
    "CASE WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '$search' THEN 1
        WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '%$search' THEN 2
        WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '$search%' THEN 3
        WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '%$search%' THEN 4
        ELSE 5 END"
);
```

After debugging the select statement created from above, I notice it is failing due to Magento inserting backticks around the `CASE` expression.

Is there a way to prevent this? Or, even better, is there a more optimised way to order by case in Magento?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39496209/using-functions-in-magento-is-adding-backticks-to-filters-with-functions-is-the

Comment: Thanks @AnkitShah! I actually found something similar just before your comment

Comment: Nice job. Great. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get this fixed. For anyone interested, the code I used was:

```
$customers_collection->getSelect()->order(
    new Zend_Db_Expr(
        "CASE WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '$search' THEN 1
        WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '%$search' THEN 2
        WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '$search%' THEN 3
        WHEN 'consult_lastname' = '%$search%' THEN 4
        ELSE 5 END"
    )
);
```

Really hope this helps others!